declarativeNetRequest for requests with 302 status codes
Does declarativeNetRequest only work for requests with the status codes 200-299?
I have a rule for a request with the status code 302, but it seems it does not apply.
I added a listener for chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug, but it won`t fire.

The rule might not work because your host_permissions don't include this site. Otherwise, it's either a bug or redirects are handled automatically. Anyway, you can suggest implementing support for status code condition in WECG.
